# Ansible playbook for unzipping GZ and ZIP files

Tags: ansible

I have an integration where I download one or more ZIP files. Within those ZIP files, there are dozens of GZ files that also need to be uncompressed. Below is an example of the file structure:

```
metrics.zip
-> 239238923323.gz
-> 839389239232.gz
-> 928392892839.gz
metrics-001.zip
-> 29389238923.gz
-> 39828393822.gz
-> 09320930323.gz
(etc)
```

I was struggling to write the playbook needed to loop through the ZIP file(s), then all of the GZ files and uncompress them all.

Comment: Do not post answers within your question. Post answers in the answer section!

Comment: This is a duplicate of your [previously closed question](/questions/73535400/ansible-playbook-for-unzipping-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created an answer from the author's original post:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    #   Download the report into a temporary directory on the Ansible Playbook host
    - name: Create temporary directory 
      ansible.builtin.tempfile:
        state: directory
        suffix: unique_suffix
      register: temp_dir

    - name: Download File
      ansible.builtin.get_url:
        url: "https://path.to/file/download.zip"
        dest: "{{ temp_dir.path }}/download_file_name.zip"

    #   Unzip the ZIP files
    - name: Extract all ZIP files
      ansible.builtin.unarchive:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ temp_dir.path }}"
      with_fileglob:
        - "{{ temp_dir.path }}/*.zip"

    # Unzip the GZ files
    - name: Extract all of the GZ files
      ansible.builtin.command: find "{{ temp_dir.path }}" -name '*.gz' -exec gzip -d {} \;

    - name: Merge CSVs into a single file
      ansible.builtin.assemble:
        src: "{{ temp_dir.path }}"
        dest: "{{ temp_dir.path }}/extract.x"
        regexp: '\.csv$'

#   Use a Windows host to copy the file over to a file share (copying from Linux to a Windows file share requires mounting the FS. Using a Windows host is easier)
- hosts: "{{ windows_host_name_in_inventory }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Copy Extract file to File Share
      win_copy:
        src: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['temp_dir'].path }}/extract.x"
        dest: "{{ Extract_To }}\\unique_name.csv"

#   Remove the Temporary folder
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Remove Temporary Directory
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['temp_dir'].path }}"
        state: absent
      when: hostvars['localhost']['temp_dir'].path is defined
```